# hibernate simultaneous updates

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider a scenario- 2 applications accessing/updating a single database. one of the applications is using hibernate & has got some records from db, will now process them & save it back. But before it saves, the same set of records is updated by the other application. What will happen in this scenario? 
Will hibernate throw an error on saving ? or hibernate will have the intelligence to sync the updated records?

Comment: I believe this is a general scenario and it should work fine. I think its the database which is managing this not hibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hibernate will throw `StaleObjectException`. Here is [why](http://turgaykivrak.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/72/).

Hibernate uses [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) to handle database concurrency. A `StaleObjectException`is thrown if the data to be updated is modified by another transaction before current transaction commits the changes.

EDIT:

*and how does hibernate identify that the state of object in memory is stale?*

Hibernate uses a version field to track the changes to the entity. This version field updated on every commit. Now if the version number just before commit does not match the version number when the entity was read at the beginning of transaction,`StaleObjectException` is thrown.

Comment: and how do we recover from this exception? bcoz if this situation occurs in production, what is the way out ?

Comment: and how does hibernate identify that the state of object in memory is stale ?

Comment: Recovery from exception is subjective and there are no best practices. Please check [this discussion thread.](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=942461&highlight=retry) Hibernate3 seems to have some solution for this.